# How does this repository have an active GitHub page?

Tags: git, github, github-pages, web-hosting

I came across [this repository of Fossasia](https://github.com/fossasia/badge-magic-android/) and it has [an active GitHub page](https://fossasia.github.io/badge-magic-android/) but the repository has no HTML file. How is the page  then deployed from this repository?

How can I clone a branch and work on it? Whenever I'm cloning the *gh-pages* branch, the main branch is getting cloned.

[Repository](https://github.com/fossasia/badge-magic-android)

[image]

[Website](https://fossasia.github.io/badge-magic-android/)

[image]

Comment: From the gh-pages branch, as githubs documentation about github pages states.

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll check the documentation.

Comment: Well, how can I clone a branch and work on it? Whenever I'm cloning the gh-pages branch the main branch is getting cloned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning a repository clones *all of the commits* and *none of the branches*.

That's OK, because those are *their* branches.  In your clone, you will get *your own branches*.  What matters aren't the branches, but rather the *commits*—and you already got all the commits.

If you'd like to create your own branch name that matches someone else's branch name, after you've cloned someone else's repository, Git makes that easy:

```
git switch gh-pages
```

for instance will create for you a new branch, `gh-pages`, referring to the *same commit* that your Git is remembering via `origin/gh-pages`.

You don't need a *branch name* to use a commit.  You can use a commit directly, in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  The drawback to using detached HEAD mode is that if you make any *new* commits, you may not be able to *find them again later*.  That's because the way we find commits, in general, is to use branch names.

So remember: in Git, the purpose of a *branch name* is to help you *find particular commits*.  It's the commits, not the branch name, that matter.  If you had some other way to find them—besides branch names—you could use that instead, but branch names are the convenient way to find the commits.  Clones do not share branch names, though.  They only share *commits:* when you make new commits in your repository, you will need to use `git push` to *send* those commits to someone else (some other Git repository).

When you do send those commits to another Git repository, you'll want to ask them—the other Git repository—to create or update a *branch name* in their repository, so that *they* can find the commits.  But again, it's the *commits* that actually matter.  When you think about Git, you should think about commits, not branches.